# showing that the pair of Finite Automata are equivalent

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

Here I am trying to show that the pair of Finite Automata are equivalent. I have tried something but I am not sure if I am in the right direction. This is what I have.

These are pairs of FA's. Set theory formula in here is `(L1' + L2)' + (L2' + L2)'`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Conclusion:

> Both machines (FA1'+FA2)' and (FA2+FA1)' has no final states.
>   (FA1'+FA2)' to have a final state, the machine (FA1'+FA2)' must have
>   no final state. The exact same thing half of the formula. Clearly, if
>   we added these machines together we would get a machine with nine
>   state and no final state. Because there is no final state, it accepts
>   no words and two languages L1 and L2 ar equivalent.
>
> So the two regular expressions defame the same language and
>   equivalent.

Am I in the right direction ?

Comment: "These are pairs of FA's. Set theory formula in here is" -- I don't know what you are trying to say. Seems to be in the category "it's not even wrong".

Comment: Also, why did you remove large parts of your question? The remainder was useless. Are you trying to cover your tracks after cheating?

Comment: @Raphael I manage to understand what was intended. The question is a total mess. And the answer concerns only a detail and thus does not clear the mess. There is no way that (L1' + L2)' + (L2' + L2)' can be understood as a symetrical difference which is supposed to be the union of 2 intersections, or the sum of two products. What are the voters thinking of ??? True though that the answerer understood the question ... strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach works. You are effectively showing that the *symmetric difference* $L(FA_1) \Delta L(FA_2)$ is empty, hence $L(FA_1) = L(FA_2)$.

A more direct, automaton-level approach would be to build the following *product automaton* $A = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$:

- $Q = Q_1 \times Q_2$
- $\delta((q_1, q_2), a) = (\delta(q_1, a), \delta(q_2, a)) \ \forall (q_1, q_2) \in Q, a \in \Sigma$
- $q_0 = (q_{0,1}, q_{0,2})$
- $F = \{(q_1, q_2) \in Q \mid q_1 \in F_1 \Leftrightarrow q_2 \in F_2\}$

Intuitively, you keep in mind the current state in both $FA_1$ and $FA_2$. Initially, the current states are the respective initial states $q_{0,1}$ and $q_{0,2}$. Then, for each input symbol $a$, you move to the respective successor in each automaton, and note the successor state (the combination of the two successor states as a pair). Of course you only draw the state for each combination only once. You can proceed either breadth-first (considering all input symbols for one product state before moving on to a newly introduced state) or depth-first (always continue with the newly introduced state and backtracking if all product successor already existed).

Note that this way you might not have to construct the full product set $Q_1 \times Q_2$, as you automatically prune unreachable states (you don't ever introduce them). However, the product automaton in your example will have no more than 6 states anyway, so it is rather small.

Comment: thanks for your input...I don't understand the math syntax very much, I will look over you answer again until I completely understand.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Once you have built the product, what do you do with it to answer the question. cc@Dana

Comment: The question is a total gibberish that you somehow managed to outguess. This answer can be satisfactory only if you explain clearly what the question intended to do (your first sentence does it in a way), and repeat correctly the erroneous formula given for symmetrical difference. Make it something useful for other readers.  I am still surprised by this answer, as it seems a hard way to do things. Taking the complement is not necessarily cheap. It is more a theoretical construct than a practical way to do things, I would think. Given these automata, there might be an easier way.

Comment: I acknowledge there is room for improvement and if I find the time I will update it. But the formula for the symmetric difference given in the question is correct (it equals $(L_1 \cap L_2^\complement) \cup (L_1^\complement \cap L_2) = (L_1 \setminus L_2) \cup (L_2 \setminus L_1)$. Furthermore, for $L$ derived from regular languages $L_1, L_2$ through $L = \{ w \mid w \in L_1 \bowtie w \in L_2\}$ you can construct an automaton using product construction and applying $\bowtie$ to the acceptance predicate. I forgot to mention that the resulting DFA has to accept $\Sigma^*$, which it does.