# Sharing of two language L1 and L2 regularity question

Tags: finite-automata

We call the sharing of two languages L1 , L2   to be the set of all strings that are in both or neither of L1  and L2 . If L1  and L2  are regular, then the sharing of L1  and L2  is regular. True or false?

Apparently the answer is false but that confuses me because can't the sharing of L1 and L2 be all the strings that are neither in L1 and L2, which means that they could be nonregular strings? Or am I just not understanding this...

Comment: You might want to edit your question to make it a question.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/21897/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52853/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2851/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22000/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties

Comment: Actually the complement of the symmetric difference of two regular languages *is* regular. This easily follows from classical closure properties.